# System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, system.web.caching

Please tell me about `System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration` in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178597.aspx) from MSDN - NoSlidingExpiration *Specifies that an item expires at a set time, regardless of how often it is accessed. For example, you can set an item to expire at 6:00 PM or after four hours.*

If there was something else you wanted to ask about, please edit your question so we can help further.