# Cache.NoSlidingExpiration in ASP - when is it reset?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I have found an answer to a similar question ([System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration in asp.net c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819144/system-web-caching-cache-noslidingexpiration-in-asp-net-c)) and followed the links, but I need more specific information I cannot find.

NoSlidingExpiration does not reset when you 'access' it. But, does that mean when you read it? Or also when you write it?

For example, if I do

```
Cache.Insert("mykey", 42, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

and then 10 minutes later, I do:

```
Cache.Insert("mykey", 42, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

again, will the expiry be adjusted?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the MSDN doc on [Cache.NoSlidingExpiration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.noslidingexpiration.aspx)

> When used, this field sets the slidingExpiration parameter to the
>   TimeSpan.Zero field, which has a constant value of zero. The cached
>   item expires in accordance with the absoluteExpiration parameter
>   associated with the Insert or Add method call.

That means when you call `Add` or `Insert`, whatever the `absoluteExpiration` value you have given in that call will be used to expire that item. So in your example:

`DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20)`

means the item will be reset after 20 minutes.